# Azure: How to use custom module in State Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-automation, dsc, powershell-dsc

I created a class based DSC Resource as a Powershell Module and successfully uploaded it to
`Azure Automation`/`Modules`. It has a green icon and seems to be added successfully. Now I want to use this module in `State Configuration` file. So I created configuration like this:

```
Configuration Temp01 {

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'MyModule' -ModuleVersion 1.0.0

    Node 'localhost' {
      MyResource Test01 {
          Param = ...
      }
    }

}
```

compiling this configuration on Azure

[image]

fails with error:

```
Exception calling "NewScriptBlock" with "1" argument(s): "At line:3 char:5 + Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'MyModule' -ModuleVersion 1. ... +
~~~~~~~ Could not find the module '<MyModule, 1.0.0>'." (At line:3 char:5 + Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'MyModule' -
```

What should I do ? How I could use my custom module in `State Configuration` ?

Comment: Have you checked this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/resources/authoringresourceclass?view=dsc-1.1). @Alex F

Comment: Yes - I already created mu custom DSC resource and uploaded it to Azure Automation/Modules. I tested my resource locally and it works OK. Now I want to actually use it in Azure Automation 'State Configuration' process but get an error as above :( Any idea what I should do to make it work ?

Comment: Have you checked the `ModuleVersion` property matches the version you are specifying in your configuration and Azure Automation modules? @Alex F

Comment: yes - I tipple checked all settings possible. There's only 1 version of resource. I guess the main issue is that my Resource is not uploaded/downloaded to machine where the configuration is compiled....

Comment: Have you imported the `nx` module along with your `mymodule`? It must be imported to compile the DSC resources. @Alex F

Comment: `nx` module ? sorry - I am new to Azure - could you elaborate a little bit more about this process ? May be a link to documentation or example ?

Comment: Can you check this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/quickstarts/dsc-configuration#import-modules)! @Alex F

Comment: yes - this is exactly the process that I am doing. In my case the module is not in Powershell Gallery - I uploaded to Automation Account shared modules

Comment: Then have you installed the `nx` module in shared modules?  @Alex F

Comment: Are you following the same process as in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/quickstarts/dsc-configuration#import-modules)? @Alex F

Answer (score 0):

After a workaround on your issue, the process and configuration set up you have followed is good to me. Check below points that might be the cause of the conflicts.

- Check that the module has been uploaded completely and also check that the version of the module you are uploading is matches with the DSC configuration modules.
- `ModuleVersion` property matches the version you are specifying in your configuration and Azure Automation modules.
- Import the `nx` module along with your `mymodule`. It must be imported to compile the DSC resources if you are using PowerShell gallery.
  Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/quickstarts/dsc-configuration#sign-in-to-azure) for more relevant information.

[image]

- Make sure that the path of the located module is appropriately given. Instead of passing module name directly, provide the path of the module as shown.

`Import-Module -Name 'C:\path\Module.psd1' -ModuleVersion 1.0.0`

- Verify the correct module version is available on the target nodes as you are using Automation account on VM's.
- Also go to `Virtual machine >> Extensions + applications >> Check the version is matching with your uploaded version`.

[image]

- If still the issue persists, use [`Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psdesiredstateconfiguration/set-dsclocalconfigurationmanager?view=dsc-1.1) command before importing the DSC resource to apply LCM settings prior with the required version.

Comment: I guess there's some mis-understanding. I want to say that there's no PATH to module, there's no Powershell commands - sorry. All it's done on Azure Automation account. I upload zip file to Modules and **on another page** I write State Configuration file. **I don't compile the file** - it is done by Azure Automation (as you linked in your answer). I triple checked the 'versions' and other configurations.... Yes - my DSC resource **works OK** if I run it locally from physical machine - it does not work on Azure Automation. P.S. What about this 'nx' module ? This is was just example for Galery

Comment: **Please use Azure Portal for all steps**

Comment: I've also used the same Azure Portal for the above configuration. Are you still facing the same issue? @AlexF